# Xslt loop through different nodes and combine in BizTalk map

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, biztalk

I want to compare two records in a single xml file and fetch the matching records. (Note: I will not be able to change the InputSchema)

> The InputRequest1 contains Identifiers (ID and IDScheme) and which I
>   want to compare with InputRequest2 which contains multiple Products
>   and corresponding Identifiers (ID and IDScheme) and Login detials (ID
>   and IDScheme - Login). I should compare the InputRequest1 to the
>   InputRequest2 nodes and extract the matching Product details to form
>   the Output. The Output should contain the Login and ID details as
>   shown in the example below.

Sample XML:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema">
  <InputMessagePart_0>
    <ns1:InputRequest1 xmlns:ns1="http://myClient/schema/5.0.0/">
      <ns1:Identifier>
        <ns1:ID>123456</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:IDScheme>ABC</ns1:IDScheme>
      </ns1:Identifier>
      <ns1:Identifier>
        <ns1:ID>654321</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:IDScheme>CBA</ns1:IDScheme>
      </ns1:Identifier>
      <ns1:Identifier>
        <ns1:ID>2356152</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:IDScheme>ZZZ</ns1:IDScheme>
      </ns1:Identifier>
    </ns1:InputRequest1>
  </InputMessagePart_0>
  <InputMessagePart_1>
    <ns1:InputRequest2 xmlns:ns1="http://myClient/schema/5.0.0/">
      <ns1:Products>
        <ns1:ProfileContext>
          <ns1:LoginID>
            <ns1:ID>login123</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:IDScheme>USERID</ns1:IDScheme>
          </ns1:LoginID>
        </ns1:ProfileContext>
        <ns1:ProductDetails>
          <ns1:ProductIdentifier>
            <ns1:ID>123456</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:IDScheme>ABC</ns1:IDScheme>
          </ns1:ProductIdentifier>
        </ns1:ProductDetails>
      </ns1:Products>
      <ns1:Products>
        <ns1:ProfileContext>
          <ns1:MemberIdentifier>
            <ns1:ID>login789</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:IDScheme>USERTID</ns1:IDScheme>
          </ns1:MemberIdentifier>
        </ns1:ProfileContext>
        <ns1:ProductDetails>
          <ns1:ProductIdentifier>
            <ns1:ID>9876543</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:IDScheme>DEF</ns1:IDScheme>
          </ns1:ProductIdentifier>
        </ns1:ProductDetails>
      </ns1:Products>
      <ns1:Products>
        <ns1:ProfileContext>
          <ns1:MemberIdentifier>
            <ns1:ID>login456</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:IDScheme>USERTID</ns1:IDScheme>
          </ns1:MemberIdentifier>
        </ns1:ProfileContext>
        <ns1:ProductDetails>
          <ns1:ProductIdentifier>
            <ns1:ID>456789</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:IDScheme>CBA</ns1:IDScheme>
          </ns1:ProductIdentifier>
        </ns1:ProductDetails>
      </ns1:Products>
    </ns1:InputRequest2>
  </InputMessagePart_1>
</ns0:Root>
```

**I want the output to be:**

```
<ns1:OutputRequest xmlns:ns1="http://myClientOutput/schema/5.0.0/">
  <ns1:Identifier>
    <ns1:ID>login123</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:IDScheme>USERID</ns1:IDScheme>
  </ns1:Identifier>
  <ns1:Identifier>
    <ns1:ID>123456</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:IDScheme>ABC</ns1:IDScheme>
  </ns1:Identifier>
  <ns1:Identifier>
    <ns1:ID>login456</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:IDScheme>USERID</ns1:IDScheme>
  </ns1:Identifier>
  <ns1:Identifier>
    <ns1:ID>654321</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:IDScheme>CBA</ns1:IDScheme>
  </ns1:Identifier>
</ns1:OutputRequest>
```

Can you please help me in the xslt for this transformation? Thanks.

Comment: Look into Muenchian grouping.  There are many posts about it on this site and elsewhere on the web.  If you have a more specific problem, feel free to edit this post with your more specific (and reproducible) challenge.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show what you have tried so far. Within the [scope of on-topic questions for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you should ask about a _specific problem_, by showing what you have done and where you are stuck, as opposed to just asking others to do the work for you. See also [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.

Initially I was trying to use the xpath in the for-each and since the scope in the inner for-each is different, I was unable to access the variables. But, using the variables (reading the entire node into the variable), I was able to achieve what I wanted. Below the code that got me the result.

```html
<ns0:OutputRequest>      
      <xsl:variable name="Msg1" select="InputMessagePart_0/ns0:InputRequest1/ns0:Identifier"/>
      <xsl:variable name="Msg2" select="InputMessagePart_1/ns0:InputRequest2/ns0:Products"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="$Msg1">

        <xsl:variable name="RequestID"  select="ns0:Identifier/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="RequestIDScheme"  select="ns0:IdentifierScheme/text()" />

        <xsl:for-each select="$Msg2">
          <xsl:variable name="LoginID" select="ns0:ProfileContext/ns0:LoginID/ns0:ID/text()"/>
          <xsl:variable name="LoginIDScheme" select="ns0:ProfileContext/ns0:LoginID/ns0:IDScheme/text()"/>
          <xsl:variable name="ResponseID"  select="ns0:ProductDetails/ns0:ProductIdentifier/ns0:ID/text()" />
          <xsl:variable name="ResponseIDScheme"  select="ns0:ProductDetails/ns0:ProductIdentifier/ns0:IDScheme/text()" />
          
            <xsl:if test="$RequestID = $ResponseID and $RequestIDScheme = $ResponseIDScheme">
              <ns0:Identifier>
                <ns0:ID>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$LoginID" />
                </ns0:ID>
                <ns0:IDScheme>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$LoginIDScheme" />
                </ns0:IDScheme>
              </ns0:Identifier>
              <ns0:Identifier>
                <ns0:ID>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$ResponseID" />
                </ns0:ID>
                <ns0:IDScheme>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$ResponseIDScheme" />
                </ns0:IDScheme>
              </ns0:Identifier>
            </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>      
      </xsl:if>
    </ns0:OutputRequest>
```

Thanks again.